# JSON undefined when looking with string

Tags: json

I'm not quite sure what my problem is here.

This is my json:

```
user = {
    userdata: {
        name: "Test"
    }
}
```

And while user.userdata.name returns Test,
user["userdata.name"] returns undefined.

Also user["userdata"] is returning the userdata json just as well. And user["userdata"]["name"] is also returning Test.

I'm using the same method on another json, but not searching to deep. just for userdata. and there is works just fine...

Comment: *"This is my json"* No, it isn't. It's a JavaScript object initializer being assigned to a variable. JSON is a *textual* notation for data exchange (and doesn't have the `=` operator, because it's not a programming language). If you're in JavaScript source code, and not talking about the contents of a string, it's not JSON.

Comment: What about `user["userdata"]["name"] `.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And while user.userdata.name returns Test, user["userdata.name"] returns undefined.

Correct. The bit in quotes is used, in its *entirety*, as the property name to look up. It's not parsed. Since your `user` object doesn't have a property called `userdata.name` (it has `userdata`, which in turn has `name`), the value you get is `undefined`.

If you wanted to access that name with brackets notation it would be `user["userdata"]["name"]` (where the strings can be literal strings, as shown, or the result of any expression such as a variable lookup, string concatenation, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Can Access like this.

```
user["userdata"]["name"]
```